# O(n^3*log(n)) vs O(n^2*log(n))

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, analysis

[image]

I'm having a hard time analyzing the runtime complexity of this algorithm.
I know the first while loop runs n times.
The inner while loops run at log(n) since k is divided by 2 every iteration.
I'm pretty sure the for loop has a runtime of an arithmetic series. (the sum is n^2/2)
So to sum it all up we are supposed to have O(n^3*log(n)) runtime complexity right?
Am I somehow missing something and it is actually O(n^2*log(n))?
I've never encountered algorithms with n^3*log(n) runtime so it kind of threw me off.
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: "I'm pretty sure the for loop has a runtime of an arithmetic series" what makes you think that? do you think it is very different from `j <- 1; while j < i; (inner loop); j <- j + 1`?

Comment: The while loop runs n time as i grows from 1 to n.
The for loop initiates j as 1 and it is updated until j reaches i.
every iteration of the while loop i grows by 1, so the for loop is iterated upon i times aka 1 time + 2 times + 3 times + ... + n times. That is a sum of an arithmetic series where d=1. 
The sum will be (n(a1+an))/2 which comes out to n^2/2, or am I wrong?

Comment: "The while loop runs n time as i grows from 1 to n." correct, although unrelated to my previous comment. (case in point: you're not considering the complexity of the outer while loop, when looking at the complexity of the inner while loop. Why should you for the for loop, then?

Comment: I am considering the complexity of the outer while loop - it runs n times.
The for loop runs n^2/2 times.
The inner while loops are nested in the for loop but not in themselves so we have log(n)
Doesn't that all come out to be O(n^3*log(n))? 
Assume the given algorithm is not changeable

Comment: "The for loop runs n^2/2 times" you're considering how many times the combination "while loop + for loop" is running. If you look at only the for loop, it's `n/2` only

Comment: *The for loop runs n^2/2 times* In total, not each time the outer loop runs.

Comment: @njzk2 Could you explain why n^2/2 is the combination of the while + for loops and not the for loop only? For example, if i=2 and i < n so we enter the for loop - j is initiated to 1 and the for loop runs once, then j is updated to 2 and the for loop runs twice, or am I getting it wrong and for every j update the for loop runs only ONE extra time?

Comment: @n.m. But that's what I'm saying, if the for loop runs n^2/2 times in total, the outer loop runs n times and the inner while loop runs log(n) times doesn't that come out as n*(n^2/2)*log(n) = O(n^3*log(n))?

Comment: Consider a simpler example. `for i = 1 to n for j = 1 to i print ('*')`. Set n = 5. How many asterisks will be printed? Closer to 5^2/2 or 5^3/2? Write a program and check.

Comment: "if the for loop runs n^2/2 times in total" then why would you consider the inner while loops run only log(n)?

Comment: @n.m. 
'def check(n):
    counter = 0 
    for i in range(1,n):
        for j in range(1,i):
            counter += 1
    return counter'

This returned 6 for n=5 , I guess it's closer to 5^2/2 than 5^3/2 

Would it be a sum of an arithmetic series if j were to go from 1 to n? Or not even then?

I am trying to figure out for later when do I take the while+for loops as a combination or do I always have to consider them individually?

Thank you guys for the answers

Comment: How about just formulating as mathematical integrals and simply calculate it?

Comment: @Sebastian I never learned how to do that in my course, we were taught a specific way to analyze runtime complexity.
Care to explain your method?

Comment: Well the answer is exactly (n-1)(n-2)/2 (check for different n). Which is the sum of a progression (check `sum(range(1,n))`). That's the number of times the inner loop runs *in total*. You don't multiply it by anything else.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at the inner body where the loops with `k` happen. The assignment `k = j` halfway will potentially increase `k` a bit, but `k` will less than double there. This means we can combine both loops into one:

```
 ← 
while  > 1
     ← /2
```

Note that this does not depend on  and .

This is not *exactly* the same as the original code, but we can be sure this loop will make as many iterations as the original two loops combined, minus one. But that one follows from the increment of , but this is a constant amount of work and so not significant in big O terms.

This single loop has a complexity of O(log).

The outer two loops really produce every pair with  >=  from the values {1,..,−1}. The total number iterations made by the -loop (summing them up for every iteration of the -loop) is thus (−1)/2, which is O(²).

So we have a time complexity of O(²log).

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the complexity of the algorithm into an integral formula and calculate it mathematically.

The exact formula would use summation and really exactly count every line, but this is not necessary to get a result in O notation. So we use integrals here and count, how often the inner loops iterate.

The inner while loops half a starting value until it reaches a target value. Than can be expressed as the logarithm to the base of 2 of the starting value divided by the final value.

[image: \int_{i=1}^n\int_{j=1}^i(\log_2\frac n j+log_2,j),dj,di]

[image]

[image: =\int_{i=1}^n\Bigl(\frac{i,\ln(i) - i - 1}{\ln 2}\Bigr),di]

= [image]

[image: O(n^2,\log n)]

Using the formulas for `integral of log_a x dx` and `integral of x * ln x dx`.

The final leading term is `(n² * ln(n) / 2) / ln(2)`.

This could be also written as `n² * log_2(n) / 2`.