# Algorithm Suggestion for finding an element in an array

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

Given an array `A` which is divided to `k` partitions of `k` elements (we can assume `n%k = 0`), where all elements of a partition are bigger than the elements in the partition to the left, and smaller than all the elements of the partition to the right.

```
i.e n=9, k=3, A=[2,1,3,4,6,5,9,7,8] -> [[2,1,3],[4,6,5],[9,7,8]]
```

Suggest an algorithm which receives an `integer x` and `returns the index of x` if it's in the array, `else return -1`.

The algorithm I suggested was a modified version of a binary search.

```
Basically, the subsets are sorted in the bigger array but not inside themselves. 
We can perform a 'binary search' to locate the subset in which x is most likely to be or not to be.
Once we find such a subset we iterate over it to look for x since it isn't sorted. If x isn't there, return -1.
```

Would such an algorithm run in a time complexity of O(k*log(n/k)) or simply O(k)? Am I completely off and should think about something else?

Comment: *"which is divided to k partitions of k elements (we can assume n%k = 0)"*: if the array is divided like that, then  is ², so it follows that % = 0. Maybe you made a mistake in your first phrase?

Comment: @greybeard, they started off by stating *"A which is divided to k partitions of k elements"*. That cannot be done with a 12 element array. By stating this they either made a mistake or tell us that A has a size that is a perfect square.

Answer (score 0):

> Given an array A which is divided into k partitions of k elements.

If `A` has the size of `n`, then these statements are true

- `n % k = 0`
- `n / k = k` or `k * k = n`

Now, this particular problem has a solution for both `O(k logk)` and `O(k)` time complexity.

First, the modified binary approach algorithm stated in your question will have `O(k logk)` time complexity ( which I think you already know about ).

So, I would like to elaborate on the `O(k)` approach which is similar to `skiplist`.

```cpp
// n = 9, k = 3, nums = [2,1,3,4,6,5,9,7,8] -> [[2,1,3],[6,4,5],[9,7,8]]

int search(vector<int>& nums, int k, int x) {
    auto n = nums.size();
    nums.push_back(INT_MAX);  // Appending INT_MAX to nums to ensure r <= n in the loop

    for (int r = k, prev_max = -1; r <= n; r += k) {  // Loop through nums with a step of k
        if (x < prev_max) break;  // If x is less than prev_max, break out of the loop
        if (x < nums[r])  // If x is less than the element at index r in nums
            for (auto l = r - k; l < r; l++) {  // Loop through the previous k elements
                if (nums[l] == x) return l;  // If x is found, return the index l
                prev_max = max(prev_max, nums[l]);  // Update prev_max with the maximum value between prev_max and the element at index l
            }
    }
    return -1;  // If x is not found, return -1
}

int main() {
    vector<int> nums = {2,1,3,4,6,5,9,7,8};
    search(nums, 3, 6); // 4
    search(nums, 3, 10); // -1
    search(nums, 3, 9); // 6
    search(nums, 3, 2); // 0
}
```

**Pseudo code**

```
FUNCTION search(nums: list of integers, k: integer, x: integer) -> integer
    n = length of nums
    append the maximum possible integer value to the end of nums

    prev_max = -1
    FOR r = k TO n step k
        IF x is less than prev_max THEN
            BREAK out of the loop
        END IF
        
        IF x is less than the element at index r in nums THEN
            FOR l = r - k TO r
                IF the element at index l in nums is equal to x THEN
                    RETURN l as the index of x in nums
                END IF
                Update prev_max to be the maximum value between prev_max and the element at index l in nums
            END FOR
        END IF
    END FOR
    
    RETURN -1 as x is not found in nums
END FUNCTION
```

Comment: The modified binary approach is already O(k).

Comment: Isn't the modified binary approach `O(klogk)` ? `logk` on the finding part and `k` on the linear searching for each `logk`?

Comment: Well, they didn't show code, but I expect it to be similar to yours. A binary search on the k elements that are the first element in each of the k partitions. That gives you two candidate partitions, which it then searches linearly. So O(log k) + O(k) = O(k).

Comment: Our ‘suggest an algorithm’ requires us to simply describe it or write it in pseudo code and not an actual script, I’m not really familiar with the syntax so if you could describe what it does that’ll be great. Although, if the binary search is O(logk) in some for loop, won’t the loop that checks the candidate partitions be a nested loop, thus making it O(klogk)?

Comment: I am also opting for `O(klogk)` being the complexity. Which script you are familiar with? This algorithm simply takes a chunk of `k` elements and checks if our target element is present in that chunk with checks that let it skip unnecessary ones. Added pseudocode.

Comment: @Vortex If you think the binary search one isn't O(k) but O(klogk), then you really should show it. Done properly, it's O(k).

Comment: @lucifer [simpler](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=fZJLasMwEIahS59ioBBsLDdxHm6ClRyhFyihGFlJhthy0KMtDTlJN9l02Qv1NJWsvLyJwFjzzz8fM2K-f9muMsp9b2vGjscfo1fJ9O_h5REFq0zJgWKjtORFvQiu2jtnupG3CquwRq1upaJaNxL1xlYahWINoqi52hWMg9JlHgQoNCheSLYJPZBaZdEDYWpFwGW3_vcZwT4Ae1wgYN46nhR-8TDKLwlpE1sffmyw4hBKoNbe88RXuQQ6t6zW4Y6E-FKxaiSEjoKWIiGxur1SqFFYTOw6EVEOcYzXelxB2JJxCfMOuaVzbaQA9PxTlKR5cPCT14VFnwe7mb9t1jaxH5KUjMiYZGRCZuSZTA8exRqjgdLz0_nXGhHIIqdyUVY59PswvmtOB113kt61z7ru7K552DUPgoNfq9N2nbfsHw)

Comment: (And the binary search would simply replace my first loop to find `r`, the rest would be identical.)

Comment: [with binary search](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=fVJLasMwEIUufYqBQrFrufk2TbCTi5RSjKzEwrIcJLktDT5JN9l02QO1p-nIipOYQARG1rw3b5408_VDt6LW9nvdULrff9dmHc3_bn5vuaSizhgkvNJGsbRceafYG6OmUucRKnjJjT4PpWJTKW5yzKw1lxuQacn0NqUMtMliz-PSgGapornvBBOMrO5A1qUmYNHCbR8B7DzAZQ8Sli3jQfNP5geo0yGiQmhIIOe4FxDBKG6x95wLBj7CCWKdVpdV8gzpFg1bdADj-ERYg2-LPVvWPRQvkCzRzhG3qy1r8bAraBcTmvVorSukOUpzdK0wjBIofrjKulLgW8QmKLxGEeNvgrnSV1gEH0UGMYQhDy598hdYXjhUzNRKAnelD6cIzTauCWWK0t27nLWifWc0sRuTEZmQKZmRR7IgT2TeOCla1QaSpOuia9yEwCywUSYzEcNgANOr5NGwz45GV-mLPnt2lTzuk4de4yb8MOjdwP8D)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75958067/on3logn-vs-on2logn?noredirect=1#comment134086632_75958067 This is the ‘syntax’ we work with in my course, we analyze time complexity with these type of pseudo codes, we were told never to try to actually write a script for the program and run it. @KellyBundy Now I see the binary search and linear search after are not nested and we do not need to multiply, thanks.